# How can I get the difference of two dates from different tables and generate it as a summary using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two dates (of same reference) from different tables that I will need to get a difference WHEN the STATUS from Table2 is equal to "STOP" or "MAX" and put it in a summary.  I know how to subtract dates but from the same table only.  Please see below to further explain my scenario because its really hard for me to complete the code.

```
Table1

REF#    BEGINDATE   
----   ----------- 
ABC1    12/31/2012   
CDE9    01/01/2013
EFG2    02/01/2013
MJK8    02/03/2013
```

```
Table2

REF#     ENDDATE      STATUS
----    ---------     ------
CDE9    03/31/2013    STOP
MJK8    05/01/2013    MAX
EFG2    02/05/2013
ABC1    02/21/2013    STOP
```

this is the Summary Result:

```
STATUS   30 below   30 to 79   80 and up
------   --------   --------   ---------
STOP                    1          1
MAX                                1
```

These are the additional infos:

a. The REF# from Table2 is always present in the Table1 (which makes the Table1 as my main table)

b. The 3 columns (30 below, 30 to 79 etc) in summary result is the count of lines per STATUS.

SO FAR, this is all I have:

```
SELECT STATUS, sum(case when *THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK* then 1 else 0 end) as 30 below,
sum(case when *THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK TOO* then 1 else 0 end) as 30 to 79,
sum(case when *NEED HELP IN THIS TOO* then 1 else 0 end) as 80 and up from Table2?
GROUP BY STATUS
```

I hope that someone could help me how to get this right, thanks in advance for your quick help. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one me freind!

```
SELECT table_1.REF, 

SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, table_1.StartDate, table_2.EndDate) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1 table_1 
JOIN table2 table_2 ON table_1.REF = table_2.REF
GROUP BY table_1.REF

WHERE table_2.STATUS in ('max', 'stop')
```

Answer (score 2):

you need something like DateDiff(day, Date1, Date2) ...

```
SELECT t1.REF, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, t1.StartDate, t2.EndDate) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.REF = t2.REF
GROUP BY t1.REF
WHERE t2.STATUS in ('MAX', 'STOP')
```

Comment: yeah i know that already.. but whats the syntax to "DATEDIFF" two dates from different tables?

Comment: join the 2 tables on the REF column

Comment: how about the "CASE WHEN STATUS = 'STOP' or STATUS = 'MAX'? where can I put it exactly?

Comment: hi.. ive got an error.. "Cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation" Error Code 446.. what can I do next?

Comment: select t2.med_stat, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),getdate()) < 90 then 1 else 0 end),
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),getdate()) between 89 and 121 then 1 else 0 end),
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),getdate()) > 120 then 1 else 0 end)
from data2002.dbo.tblCrew as t1
join eds.dbo.tblpms as t2
on t1.CaseNo = t2.CaseNo
AND t2.med_stat in ('Fit to Work','Under Medical Treatment')
group by t2.med_stat

-- sorry if my query is different from my question (confidentiality), but still i used the same logic here

Comment: change "t1.CaseNo = t2.CaseNo" to "t1.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT"

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a join.

```
SELECT t2.STATUS --SUM(case statement here  t1.BEGINDATE, t2.ENDDATE)
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2
ON t1.[REF#] = t2.[REF#]
AND t2.STATUS IN (''STOP','MAX')
GROUP BY t2.STATUS;
```

From there you can do the necessary calculations between the two dates.

For more information on joins checkout [A Month Of Joins](http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/).

The 3 `CASE` statements would have to look something like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.BEGINDATE,t2.ENDDATE) BETWEEN 30 AND 79 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: hi Sebastian.. i created a code as per your instruction but im stuck with this error.. "Cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation" Error Code 446

Comment: select t2.med_stat, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),getdate()) < 90 then 1 else 0 end),
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),getdate()) between 89 and 121 then 1 else 0 end),
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),getdate()) > 120 then 1 else 0 end)
from data2002.dbo.tblCrew as t1
join eds.dbo.tblpms as t2
on t1.CaseNo = t2.CaseNo
AND t2.med_stat in ('Fit to Work','Under Medical Treatment')
group by t2.med_stat

-- sorry if my query is different from my question (confidentiality), but i used the same logic here..